# Why is this basic if-else expression failing?

Tags: python, if-statement, chaining

This is my first post on the site. I am in my third week of coding class and have completed everything but this problem. We are using ZyBooks. I have completed everything but this participation exercise. It isn't graded; however, it is driving me nuts.
We are asked to write an expression that will print "in high school" if the value of user_grade is between 9 and 12 (inclusive).

Sample output with input: 10
in high school

This is what I have so far:
I apologize if I am posting this incorrectly.

```
user_grade = int(input())
if user_grade >= 9 <= 12:
    print('in high school')
else:
    print('not in high school')
```

The code passes all tests until it runs input: 13. Then I receive this error:

Output differs. See highlights below.

Special character legend
Your output:
in high school

Expected output:
not in high school

Comment: Please revisit the documentation on multi-part comparisons.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your order of operations in the if is slightly wrong. Do you mean the following:

```
if  9 <= user_grade <= 12:
```

Because right now you are checking:

- is 9 smaller or equal to user_grade
  AND
- is 9 smaller or equal to 12

If you enter `13` then the first check will be `True`. But as the second check is only comparing 9 and 12 it is always true. And therefore you are never testing if `user_input` is smaller or equal to 12.

Comment: I don't think it is this way, because if you try 8, it properly returns False. I think your fix is certainly right, but I think your explanation is incorrect in the order of python operations.

Comment: What do you mean by order of operations in this case?

Comment: The first check is to see if user_input is <= 9. The second check is to see if THAT value is <= 12. I believe you're saying that the first check is to determine if 9 is smaller than or equal to 12, which is what you're saying (and I agree) is of course always true. It's just that 9 and 12 are never compared.

Comment: Oh you are right, I messed up the order in my explainaition. I will try to clarify this

Comment: No worries! Good answer.

Comment: Not quite. If you enter 13, the first check will be True. This is the variable that Python will use to compare in the second case. This means the second case is True <= 12, which will be converted to 1<= 12, which is certainly True. The only check that performs work is determining if the input is >= 9. I think Python would only compare in the way you're talking about if you explicitly put in `and`.

Comment: I think your "second Check" is not actualy correct as the above is using Operator Chaining and therefore comparing the middle value against the other two

Comment: Yep - this explains it! You're totally right. You can combine them completely arbitrarily, where I was thinking it would only work if the <= signs were in the correct place. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons. Thanks for helping me with my understanding.

Comment: That code passed every test. Thank you so much 'mame98' for the fast answer. It makes a lot more sense to me after you explained what the code was doing.

Comment: @Diff_Mach please remember to accept an answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong. You should use:

```
if 9 <= user_grade <= 12:
    print('in high school')
```

The order of the comparsion matters. `user_grade >= 9 <= 12` means `user grade is inferior or equals to 9 AND 9 is inferior or equals to 12`.

Answer (score 0):

Guess that it should more readable as follows:

```
def user_grade (input):
    if input >= 9 and input <= 12:
        print('in high school')
    else:
        print('not in high school')
    
user_grade(13)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked in Zybooks:

```
user_grade = int(input())

if 9 <= user_grade and user_grade <= 12:
    print('in high school')
else:
    print('not in high school')
```

The note in the book gave a hint to the answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page to learn more about how this platform works. This seems like a comment to an existing answer. I understand that you may not be able to comment until you reach certain reputation, but posting an answer is not a workaround to making a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35040815)

Answer (score 0):

```
user_grade = int(input())

if 9 <= user_grade <= 12:

    print('in high school')

else:

    print('not in high school')
```

Ridiculous that zybooks doesn't explain that you can add a variable in between the operators.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the zybooks question is:

```
8 < user_grade < 13
```